# SQL select Name entries for which a certain requirement is NEVER fulfilled

Tags: sql, grouping, where-clause

I need to select Name entries for which none of the rows fulfills a certain requirement. This is best described as an example- lets consider the following table:

```
Name      Number    ID
A         1         2
A         2         2     
B         1         2
B         2         3
C         3         3
```

The requirement would be that Number=ID. For the name B this is never the case, so I would like to return the Name B.

```
Name      Number    ID
A         1         2
A         2         2     <---- fulfills requirement for A
B         1         2
B         2         3
C         3         3     <---- fulfills requirement for C
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS clause

```
select * from Table1 t1
where not exists (select null
                  from Table1
                  where t1.Name = Name
                  and Number = Id)
```

If you just want the names which don't fulfill the requirement, just change the select to

```
select distinct t1.Name
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5da8df/2) with both versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The crucial advice was to use the t1 specifier!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select Name
from table 
where name not  in (Select distinct name from table where number = id )
```